# Choosing and finding a good wine grape rootstock

Tags: grape-vine

I'm interested in planting about 5-10 vines of wine grapes from a mature (3-5 year old) rootstock.

Any suggestions on the particular varietal.  I'm located in the Texas Hill Country near Austin.  I'm currently focused on Lenoir (Black Spanish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, for better or worse, I have purchased and planted [Black Spanish (Lenoir)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Spanish_%28grape%29) root stock (purchased from [The Natural Gardener](http://www.naturalgardeneraustin.com/) here in Austin).  It's native to Texas, and resistant to [Phylloxera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylloxera) and [Pierce's disease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce%27s_Disease).

Two weeks in, they seem to be doing well, taking root and starting to climb along the trellis.  I'll update here again sometime in the future, if anyone is interested!

Comment: Were you given any pruning instructions?  I understand good pruning is essential to getting a good yield.

Comment: For that, I'm following the book, "From Vines to Wines", by Jeff Cox.